# Datatables sorting is wrong after changing an entry

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

i am using a https://datatables.net/ to show some data.
When i change data, in this example the age, then the **sorting no longer works correctly.**

**Is there an possibility to change this behaviour ?**

Please click e.g. on the table line from "Tiger Nixon" and the age changes. Now sort the column, it isn't correct. Another
example is on: https://jsfiddle.net/rule_34/huv547j0/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 $("#example").on('click','tr',function () { 
    var line = $(this).attr('id');
    var age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1;

    $("tr[id="+ line +"] td[data-element=age]").html(age); 
 });    
 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------      
 $('#example').DataTable(); // initialize
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered " cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="0815">
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td data-element="age">61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="1234">
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td data-element="age">63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>8422</td>
                <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2587">
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td data-element="age">66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
                <td>1562</td>
                <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="3698">
                <td>Cedric</td>
                <td>Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td data-element="age">22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
                <td>6224</td>
                <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="8547">
                <td>Airi</td>
                <td>Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td data-element="age">33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
                <td>5407</td>
                <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="5254">
                <td>Brielle</td>
                <td>Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td data-element="age">61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
                <td>4804</td>
                <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="4785">
                <td>Herrod</td>
                <td>Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td data-element="age">59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
                <td>9608</td>
                <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2312">
                <td>Rhona</td>
                <td>Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td data-element="age">55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
                <td>6200</td>
                <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thx @Nouphal.M for the note to: *fnUpdate*. With this information i built a new:
https://jsfiddle.net/rule_34/2L38yb98/1/

This is also not working correct cause i always get the wrong table line, but sorting will work fine.

So **how will i get the line for update**, even if i change sorting column ?

Comment: I'd try and look at https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html and figure out why their example works when changing the age.

Comment: Try using fnUpdate to update the binded data to datatable http://legacy.datatables.net/ref

Answer (score 0):

In datatable website it says you need to update datatable after you change it

> Description
>   If the data in the host DataTable changes, the FixedColumns must be updated to reflect this new data. This method provides the ability, simply redrawing the fixed columns with the latest data in the DataTable.

In future this will be automated once DataTables added events for table update actions, but at the moment this method must be called.

and to achieve that use this function

```
fixedColumns().update()
```

example code here:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();     
table.cell( 0, 0 ).data( 'New data' ).draw();
table.fixedColumns().update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i have found a working solution. I also have to insert *tbody* before *tr* to the event.

See also: https://jsfiddle.net/rule_34/o52r1pcy/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $("#example").on('click','tbody tr',function () { 
      var age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1; // 1..99  
      var line = $('#example').dataTable().fnGetPosition(this);    

      $('#example').dataTable().fnUpdate(age, line, 4); // 4=column Age
  });    
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------      
  $('#example').DataTable(); // initialize
} );
```